# Guice, Groovy, @Canonical and inheritance not playing nicely together

Tags: groovy, constructor, guice

I have the following Groovy classes:

```
enum Protocol {
    File,
    Ftp,
    Sftp,
    Http,
    Https
}

@Canonical
abstract class Endpoint {
    String name
    Protocol protocol
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(includeFields=true, includeSuperFields=true)
class LocalEndpoint extends Endpoint {
}

class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // Lots of stuff...
    }

  // Lots of other custom providers

  @Provides
    Endpoint providesEndpoint() {
        new LocalEndpoint('fileystem', Protocol.File)
    }
}
```

Don't worry about why I'm using a custom provider for the `Endpoint` instead of just:

```
bind(Endpoint).toInstance(new LocalEndpoint('fileystem', Protocol.File))
```

I'm 99.999% sure that's outside of this problem and is coded that way because of how the full (very large) code is wired.

My problem is that Guice and/or Groovy cannot find a constructor for `LocalEndpoint` that takes a `String` and `Protocol` argument:

```
1) Error in custom provider, groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.myapp.model.LocalEndpoint(java.lang.String, com.example.myapp.model.Protocol)
  at com.example.myapp.inject.MyAppModule.providesEndpoint(MyAppModule.groovy:130)
  while locating com.example.myapp.model.Endpoint
    for parameter 2 at com.example.myapp.inject.MyAppModule.providesConfig(MyAppModule.groovy:98)
  at com.example.myapp.inject.MyAppModule.providesConfig(MyAppModule.groovy:98)
  while locating com.example.myapp.config.MyAppConfig
```

It then spits out a large stack trace with the following listed as the cause:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.myapp.model.LocalEndpoint(java.lang.String, com.example.myapp.model.Protocol)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1731)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1534)
```

Hopefully this is something that I can tweak by modifying `Endpoint` and/or `LocalEndpoint`, perhaps I need to pass some special parameters into the `@Canonical`/`@TupleConstructor` annotations or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Qualify the parameters in the constructor new LocalEndpoint(name: 'fileystem', protocol: Protocol.File)

Comment: Thanks @ToddWCrone (+1) but I don't like the Groovy map constructor. Thanks to `@Canonical`, `@TupleConstructor` and the likes, I should be able to use a normal "Java style" constructor call. Any suggestions for how to get this working sans map constructor? Thanks again!

Comment: Qualified parameter names is better IMO.  I wouldn't spend lots of effort trying to get the more ambiguous constructor to work.  Sorry.

Comment: "Now you see that evil will always triumph because good is dumb."

Comment: I guess I'm either evil or dumb?  Either way, if you are trying to follow "Java style" in Groovy, I will judge you.  I guess I would love to understand any pitfalls for qualified parameter names in the Groovy map constructor.  I've always seen it as much better than hoping someone puts parameters in the 'correct' ordering.

Comment: Not sure if it is a problem, but apparently Canonical includes the TupleConstructor annotation.  Have you tried removing the redundant annotation or do you need it to specify that configuration?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add [`includeSuperProperties`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) in the `TupleConstructor` annotation, and that seems to resolve it, even by itself:

`@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties=true)`

So the whole thing would be:

```
@Canonical
abstract class Endpoint {
    String name
    Protocol protocol
}

@Canonical // You may not need this anymore
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties=true) 
class LocalEndpoint extends Endpoint {
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor (+1) - **that worked!!!** One quick followup question before I can award you the bounty: previously I had `includeSuperFields=true` set. Why (in my particular case) does `includeSuperProperties` work, but *not* `includeSuperFields`? What's the difference between when + where to use each of these? Thanks again!!

Comment: @smeeb Yeah that's an odd behavior.  I would expect anything captured by `includeSuperProperties` to also get anything in `includeSuperFields`.  The documentation isn't too detailed on this either, so I'm not sure.  Your best bet is probably to look over the implementation :-\